# How to configure and run Solr full dataimport from MySQL using Java?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I want to run dataimport in Solr using Java. I have gone through link [Solrj full-import not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543302/solrj-full-import-not-working), there they have just given how to run the full import command from Java, and in some other links I found how to query the Solr indexed data, but actually my requirement is, for data import we write a configuration file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db" 
            user="root" 
            password="cloudera"/>
<document>
  <entity name="emp"  
    query="select id,name from emp">
     <field column="id" name="id"/>
     <field column="name" name="name"/>       
  </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

and this configuration file information we will provide in solrconfig.xml like below

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
        </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

But my requirement is, I don't want to configure any XML file like above, just I want do it all from Java only ,so I need to set all the configurations which I have given in above XML from java code itself,i.e something like below

```
params.set("Datasource","JdbcDataSource") 
params.set("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
params.set("url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db")
params.set("user","cloudera")
params.set("password","cloudera"),etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, if you set another parameter, you can pass your entire XML as a string and execute the configuration:

```
params.set("dataConfig", <the data-import xml as string>);
```

I am late to the party, but in case anyone is looking for a solution to a similar problem, this can probably help.

Also, I would also like to mention this post, [How to do Solr Data import (i.e from RDBMS) using Java API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446644/how-to-do-solr-dataimport-i-e-from-rdbms-using-java-api/%20*How%20to%20do%20Solr%20Dataimport%20(i.e%20from%20RDBMS)%20using%20Java%20API?*).